# How can I automatically change empty String to 0 with a DocumentFilter?

Tags: java, swing, documentfilter

I want to make sure that there is always a positive Integer in my JTextField. For example, the JTextField currently has a default "1" when the GUI is created, and I want it such that if the user decides to hit backspace, instead of becoming an empty text field, I want it to automatically set the text to "0". The reason for this is because the text field also has a listener which calls a method to keep another part of the GUI updated according to this number.

I'm pretty new to DocumentFilter so I'm not even sure I'm going in the right direction but here's what I have so far:

```
public class IntegerFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offs,
        int len) throws BadLocationException {

        if (offs == 0) {
            // I'm trying to think if there's something I can put here
        } else {
            super.remove(fb, offs, len);
        }
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int len, String str,
        AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

        String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
        text += str;
        if (text.matches("\\d+")) {
            super.replace(fb, offs, len, str, a);
        }
    }
}
```

As of right now I'm overriding the remove() method of the filter and checking to see if the digit that the user is deleting is the last one. If not then delete works as regular, but if so, then nothing happens yet.

I think where I'm stuck is the fact that I want to call the replace method inside the remove method, but I don't have AttributeSet to work with.

Comment: *"I want to make sure that there is always a positive Integer in my JTextField.."*  `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(5,1,1000000,1))`

Comment: Hmm this is interesting, I hadn't looked at JSpinner before. So if I wanted to implement and incr and decr button for the number JSpinner would already have that built in?

Comment: *"..have that built in?"*  It takes no more than two lines of code to test that.

Comment: Does `JSpinner` not have a document behind it? I'm unable to cast it to `AbstractDocument` and call `getDocument()` like I would with a `JTextField`.

Comment: *"Does JSpinner not have a document behind it?"*  It has a (spinner number) model, instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // I'm trying to think if there's something I can put here

First of all your basic logic is wrong. You can't just check the offset. You could have 5 numbers in the text field and are just trying to remove the first number.

What you want to do is:

1. always invoke `super.remove(...)` to remove the digit from the Document
2. then you need to get the Document to determine how many digits are still in the Document. If the value is zero then you can invoke the super.insertString(...) method of the DocumentFilter to insert whatever value you want to be inserted into the Document.

> I don't have AttributeSet to work with.

The `AttributeSet` would be null for a JTextField.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that case for offset! This worked out great thanks.